# Moq an object created inside the method being tested

Tags: c#, moq

In the following example, I want to test the `TestMe.DoSomething()` function.

I want to mock the `ISomething` interface that is used within this method and make it return different values (depending on the specific unit test.)

In real life the `ISomething` interface winds up calling out to expensive 3rd party resources -- I definitely don't want to just call a real `ISomething`.

Here is the example structure:

```
class TestMe
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ISomething s = SomethingFactory();
        int i = s.Run();

        //do things with i that I want to test
    }

    private ISomething SomethingFactory()
    {
        return new Something();
    }
}

interface ISomething
{
    int Run();
}

class Something : ISomething
{
    public int Run()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Here is code that doesn't work:

```
        var fakeSomething = new Mock<ISomething>();
        var testMe = new TestMe();
        Mock.Get(testMe).Setup(p => p.SomethingFactory()).Returns(fakeSomething.Object);
        testMe.DoSomething();
```

Because `SomethingFactory()` is `private`, I cannot set the return value from that method to be what I want.

Any advice on how I can solve this?

Comment: An idea: inject the `ISomething` (or even refactor `SomethingFactory` into `ISomethingFactory` and inject it instead) into `TestMe` - you'll have way more options to setup your tests then.

Comment: Thought of that. But I'd rather not make such a drastic change. I think I came up with a vaguely palatable solution. See answer below.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to refactor the code too much, then your change is IMO probably the closest you can get to a clean and working solution. Otherwise, you'd have to go with dependency injection on this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the factory a full interface / class and remove the SomethingFactory method from TestMe.

```
public interface ISomethingFactory {
  ISomething MakeSomething();
}

public sealed class SomethingFactory {
  public ISomething MakeSomething() {
    return new Something();
  }
}

class TestMe
{
    private readonly ISomethingFactory _somethingFactory;

    public TestMe(ISomethingFactory somethingFactory) {
      _somethingFactory = somethingFactory;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ISomething s = _somethingFactory.MakeSomething();
        int i = s.Run();

        //do things with i that I want to test
    }
}
```

This will allow you to mock ISomethingFactory to return a mock of ISomething.

While I think you may protest this solution as too drastic a change, I think its better than making a class that's not sealed with a members who's only reason for being virtual is for testing.

Comment: This really is the best answer, and what I ultimately wound up doing: The "protected" answer below works, also, but is not as clean of a solution. I am still vaguely unsatisfied with having to add spurious interfaces with public accessibility that have only one method (and a class with only one method) in order to facilitate testing. It is not a good solution.

Comment: @CleverHuman Testing often exposes design issues, in this case your class was violating SRP.  Its job was not only to use ISomething to do something, but to build it as well.  With this solution the building responsibility is now that of the factory.  If the factory method later needs to perform other logic to actually build the instance, it can be added there.  I do understand your point, and it can be taken too far where you have lots of interfaces with only one method or property, but that's where your experience must come into play to judge tradeoffs between clean code and iface explosion.

Answer (score 1):

Changing SomethingFactory() to be protected virtual allows you to use Moq.Protected to access the method by its name:

```
public class TestMe 
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ISomething s = SomethingFactory();
        int i = s.Run();

        //do things with i that I want to test
    }

    protected virtual ISomething SomethingFactory()
    {
        return new Something();
    }
}

public interface ISomething
{
    int Run();
}

public class Something : ISomething
{
    public int Run()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

So you can run this test:

```
        var fakeSomething = new Mock<ISomething>();
        fakeSomething.Setup(p => p.Run()).Returns(2);
        var testMe = new Mock<TestMe>();
        testMe.Protected().Setup<ISomething>("SomethingFactory").Returns(fakeSomething.Object);
        testMe.Object.DoSomething();
```

Comment: That's generally a bad idea to access protected methods. See the other answer for proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can inject your dependency. If you don't want to break all your callers you can add two constructors and use the one that lets you inject fake in tests

   ```
   class TestMe
   {
       private readonly ISomething something;
       TestMe() : this(new RealSomething()
       {
       }
       TestMe(ISomething sth)
       {
           something = sth;
       }

       public void DoSomething()
       {
           ISomething s = SomethingFactory();
           int i = s.Run();

           //do things with i that I want to test
       }

       private ISomething SomethingFactory()
       {
           return new Something();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Second way would be to change the

   ```
   SomethingFactory
   ```

   method to protected virtual and override it in derived class and use that class instead, or to setup

   ```
   class TestableTestMe : TestMe
   {
       private readonly ISomething something;
       TestableTestMe(ISomething testSpecific)
       {
           something  = testSpecific;
       }


       public void DoSomething()
       {
           ISomething s = SomethingFactory();
           int i = s.Run();

           //do things with i that I want to test
       }

       protected override ISomething SomethingFactory()
       {
           return something;
       }
   }
   ```

This technique is called "extract and override"